# How do I invoke a powershell script from C# without using the Powershell class

Tags: c#, powershell

How do I invoke a powershell script from C# without using the Powershell class.

If I cannot use Process class what do I need to do.

Comment: Why can't you use the `Process` class? Or the `Powershell` class (whichever class you mean by that)? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Because these apparently do not exist in Windows 10 UWP (no System.Management.Automation and no new Process()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why wouldnt you be able to use the process class? That really is the option you have to execute some commands, unless there is a form of a C# API available for powershell....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx

a sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706564(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the script already exists as a file, you can use the Process class to start Powershell, and give it the file name as a command line argument.